# Интонации могут дрожать?

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов

> Но главное, что обратило на себя внимание, её интонации. Они были
>   исполнены такой глубокой нежности и дрожали от такой неподдельной
>   материнской гордости, что все первые ряды заметно оживились.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне такое выражение **кажется некорректным,** лучше написать так:

Но главное, что обратило на себя внимание, — это  её интонации. Голос (актрисы) был исполнен такой глубокой нежности и дрожал от такой неподдельной материнской гордости, что все первые ряды заметно оживились.